# Finding near intersections in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have the two arrays:

```
var a = [126, 619, 4192, 753, 901];
var b = [413, 628, 131, 3563, 19];
```

How can I find elements in both arrays that are close to each other to a certain percent?
For example the following function is defined,

```
function f(array1, array2, percentage)
```

such that

```
f(a, b, 5);
```

would return

```
[126, 131], [619, 628]
```

Comment: can your function be replaced by `function (array, percentage)` and you use it twice ? or I missed a relation between the two arrays ?

Comment: Do you want an item in the second array to be in the range given by +/- the percentage of an item in the first array, or an item in the first array to be in the range given by +/- the percentage of an item in the second array?

Comment: @Oriol percentage of an element of an array

Comment: @CMPS there is a relation between the two arrays

Comment: Yeah, but which array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to compare each element of array1 to every element of array2, there is no shortcut there. It can be easily done by nested loops. A possible solution:

```
function f(array1, array2, percentage) {
    var result = [];
    percentage /= 100;

    array1.forEach(function(m){
        var maxDiff = m * percentage;
        array2.forEach(function(n){         
            if(Math.abs(m - n) < maxDiff) {
                result.push([m, n]);
            }                   
        });
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the two arrays, and multiply the items of the first one by 1 ± the desired factor.

```js
function* intersect(a, b, factor=0) {
  factor /= 100;
  for(let i of a)
    for(let j of b)
      if(j <= i*(1+factor) && j >= i*(1-factor))
        yield [i, j];
}
var a = [126, 619, 4192, 753, 901];
var b = [413, 628, 131, 3563, 19];
console.log(...intersect(a, b, 5));
```